# Kubernetes cluster deployment in packstack

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I am trying to deploy a k8s cluster in openstack rocky but after long time it fails. I've checked orchestration stack and see that kube_minions resources never completes. Checking the logs output for all the instances created:

```
[  196.817505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  215.082433] random: crng init done

Fedora 27 (Atomic Host)
Kernel 4.14.18-300.fc27.x86_64 on an x86_64 (ttyS0)

host-10-0-0-3 login: [  691.438618] bridge: filtering via 
arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts 
to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[  691.516277] Bridge firewalling registered
[  692.149217] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[  701.932912] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
```

Checking deeply in the instances I've found that in master node can not start heat-agent-service...

```
_prefix=docker.io/openstackmagnum/
atomic install --storage ostree --system --system-package no --set 
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt --name heat-container- 
agent docker.io/openstackmagnum/heat-container-agent:rocky-stable

systemctl start heat-container-agent
Failed to start heat-container-agent.service: Unit heat-container- 
agent.service not found.
2019-04-04 14:57:40,238 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running 
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-013 [5]´
```

Comment: it seems that kube_minions resource during cluster deployment stays pending till timeout...any ideas why? Openstack nodes have enough resources (16GB for master  node and 10Gb for the other node)

Comment: initial post updated